# Is a dwarf ficus lyrata the same species?

Tags: trees, tropical

Title says it all. I'm just wondering how they differ from the standard ficus lyrata. is it genetic - were they bred to be smaller? Some special type of propagation from the tree? Or will the plant grow to be full size if I put it in a larger pot?
Thanks!